# Standalone class is failing to impersonate as logged on user

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# worker class (not part of an ASPX page) that does some SQL connections.  The class itself is static and instantiated by an ASMX web service.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AjaxServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This calls the worker class for the long-running process.
    /// </summary>
    static RunCreatorClient workProcessor = new RunCreatorClient();

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public String StartProcess(DateTime date, string name) //starts the process
```

Inside the worker class, I have code that connects to SQL server and executes command.  The problem is, **I can't get SYSTEM_USER to equal the logged on user.**  It always connects to SQL as the executing machine name.

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
```

This method `StartProcessing()` kicks off the SQL jobs.

```
/// <summary>
/// Worker class that executes a long-running process.
/// </summary>
public class RunCreatorClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Non-blocking call that starts running the long-running process.
    /// </summary>
    public void StartProcessing()
    {
        // Reset the properties that report status.
        IsComplete = false;
        IsRunning = true;
        PercentComplete = 0;

        // Kick off the actual, private long-running process in a new Task
        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            CommitToDb();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose `CommitToDb()` in an impersonating context.

```
using System.Security.Principal;
WindowsIdentity impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

// Kick off the actual, private long-running process in a new Task
task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    using(WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = impersonatedUser.Impersonate())
    {
        CommitToDb();
    }
});
```